# grub-install error after update

Tags: 14.04, grub2

Yesterday I did an apt-get update on my machine:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
```

During the update process I got an error saying that grub-install failed. Also the update stopped.
Now when I manually try to run grub-install I get the same error:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: disk `mduuid/32f3800c32f8e591df70a045db28f609' not found.
```

This is what fdisk -l says:

```
fdisk -l
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 363376 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 * 1 4294967295 2147483647+ ee GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/md2: 2991.3 GB, 2991329640448 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 730305088 cylinders, total 5842440704 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table


Disk /dev/md0: 8585 MB, 8585674752 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2096112 cylinders, total 16768896 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table


Disk /dev/md1: 536 MB, 536543232 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 130992 cylinders, total 1047936 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

There are two disks running a software raid. This is the output of mdadm:

```
mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 name=rescue:2 UUID=49425383:18f73adb:6ebb09e6:fc69e14a
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=rescue:0 UUID=861ecfae:2c015de6:229d0894:82819cc0
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 name=rescue:1    UUID=32f3800c:32f8e591:df70a045:db28f609
```

Which fits to the content of my mdadm.conf:

```
cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

HOMEHOST <system>

MAILADDR root

ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=861ecfae:2c015de6:229d0894:82819cc0 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=32f3800c:32f8e591:df70a045:db28f609    name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 UUID=49425383:18f73adb:6ebb09e6:fc69e14a name=rescue:2
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: might be a coincident but the failing disk also is shifted in the configs. Maybe there is some invisible character in the conf file?
You could check with vim by opening the file and type ':set list' and enter, to remove a possible character press insert and remove it.

Comment: Nope, thats not the problem, thanks for the thint :-)